# Modifying string resources inside a DLL file

Tags: dll, patch, hex-editors

Is it safe to replace some characters of a string resides in a DLL file using a Hex Editor? I'm not going to introduce new chars or remove any existing one, so the file size won't be changed. And what I am going to do is to replace some embedded SQL string which is written in lower-case, and make the chars of that string upper-case. Is it OK, or does it corrupt the DLL and make it unloadable? By the way, this DLL is not digitally signed with a code signing certificate.

Comment: If it isn't signed then you can hack all you want.  As with many questions at SO, the proof is in the pudding.

Comment: u could use http://reflexil.net/

Comment: @Simon: This is a native library, not managed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless the owner of the dll does some kind of validation of it, using a checksum for instance, it won't break anything.

(afaik most windows system dlls are watched somehow for modifications and windows will complain if you change them)

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of System File Check feature of Windows, but in this case this is not a Windows DLL.